# How to lock post_delete method of Child model when delete Parent model using CASCADE in django?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```
class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**signals.py**

```
@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Parent)
def delete_parent(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # something
```

```
@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Child)
def delete_child(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # something
```

When `delete_parent()` signal works, `delete_child()` signal should not work. How to do this?

I tried this,

```
@receiver(signals.post_delete, sender=Child)
def delete_child(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
        parent = instance.parent
        # something
    except:
        return
```

But don't work.

Comment: what about using SET_NULL instead of  CASCADE? instead of post_delete signal

Comment: check pre_delete solves the issue of getting instance.parent